# How do parskip and similar parameters behave

Tags: vertical-alignment, tex-core, parskip

Im trying to format a twocolumn article document with some twocolumn spanning graphics, small tables etc.
I used `\raggedbottom`for evading huge whitespace/glue in my text, but sometimes the space this adds is too much and the bottom lines of both columns are not aligned. Now I tried playing with paragraph lengths and `parskip` .

Setting parskip to `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.1in minus 0.01in}` seems to give good results, but in some place the space between paragraphs is still more than I want it too and the new parskip length should allow (i use font size 9, and sometimes space between paragraphs is 0.5in ...).

I changed it to `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.005in minus 0.01in}` and get exactly the same lengths as before. Also, removing the `plus 0.1in` from the code makes the text behave like I was using `\raggedbottom`.

So my question is, how does parskip behave, and how can I force it to use the values Im trying to implement?

Comment: Don't you have underfull `\vbox` warnings? If TeX doesn't have enough stretchability to fulfill the constraints, it will overstretch what it has, and warn. Without an MWE, it will be difficult to provide more concrete answers.

Comment: as frougon says you will almost certainly be getting warnings that the space is over-stretched, but also allowing parskip to be negative seems a bad idea, it means that if the page is getting full you allow the first line of one paragraph to overprint the previous paragraph, with no warning.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\addtolength\textheight{-20.7\baselineskip}

%\setlength\parskip{0pt plus 1pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\flushbottom
\begin{document}

aaaa\\aaaa\\aaaa\\aaaa\\aaaa\\aaaa\\aaaa\\aaaa\\aaaa\\aaaa\\aaaa\\aaaa


bbb\\bbb\\bbb\\bbb\\bbb\\bbb\\bbb\\bbb\\bbb\\bbb\\bbb\\bbb\\bbb

\pagebreak
ccc

\end{document}
```

On the first page there the sum of the lines in the first and second paragraph do not add up to `\textheight`, and `\flushbottom` means there is no stretch at the end of the page and there is no stretchability in `\parskip` so no glue stretches at all so the page ends short (as if `\raggedbottom` had been in effect) but this is infinitely bad, and tex warns:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [1]
```

If however you give a little bit of stretchability to `\parskip`

```
\setlength\parskip{0pt plus 1pt}
```

Then `\parskip` is stretched to take up all the available space so that `\flushbottom` is achieved, even if `\parskip` is over-stretched. With `0pt plus 1pt` as shown here you get

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 4660) has occurred while \output is active [1]
```

If the stretchability is less, the visual output is the same but it will be infinitely bad. `0pt plus 1sp` gives

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [1]
```

Conversely if you specify that parskip may stretch enough then it is not considered bad at all. `0pt plus 5pt`  produces the same visual output but no warnings about underfull boxes.